# When poetry install is set to postCreateCommand in devcontainer.json, the git user.name is not set for some reason

Tags: git, python-poetry, vscode-devcontainer

### Abstract

Here is my `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json` file:

```json
{
    "name": "${localWorkspaceFolderBasename}",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile"
    },
    "postCreateCommand": "poetry install", // this line is problematc
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "extensions": [
                "ms-python.python",
                "njpwerner.autodocstring",
                "tamasfe.even-better-toml",
                "ms-azuretools.vscode-docker"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my `.devcontainer/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:jammy

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ARG USER=vscode

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install -y build-essential --no-install-recommends make \
        ca-certificates \
        git \
        libssl-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libbz2-dev \
        libreadline-dev \
        libsqlite3-dev \
        wget \
        curl \
        llvm \
        libncurses5-dev \
        xz-utils \
        tk-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libxmlsec1-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        liblzma-dev \
        libgl1-mesa-dev

# Python and poetry installation
USER $USER
ARG HOME="/home/$USER"
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.11

ENV PYENV_ROOT="${HOME}/.pyenv"
ENV PATH="${PYENV_ROOT}/shims:${PYENV_ROOT}/bin:${HOME}/.local/bin:$PATH"

RUN echo "done 0" \
    && curl https://pyenv.run | bash \
    && echo "done 1" \
    && pyenv install ${PYTHON_VERSION} \
    && echo "done 2" \
    && pyenv global ${PYTHON_VERSION} \
    && echo "done 3" \
    && curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 - \
    && poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true \
    && poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
    && poetry config virtualenvs.prefer-active-python true
```

If you start devcontainer with this configuration, for some reason `user.name` and `user.email` in git are empty and the commit fails; if you delete the `postCreateCommand` line, you can commit without problems.

Why does the presence or absence of `poetry install` make a difference?

If you run `poetry install` on the IDE terminal after the container has been launched, the problem does not occur.